# Trying to get a string from within a <p> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the string Test123 in the following with jQuery:

```
<div id="pri_txt"><p>Test123</p></div>
```

I used:

```
var str = $('#pri_txt').next('p').text();
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Close. `next()` will select the elements next sibling. What you're looking for is its child `p` tag. Use the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) `jQuery('ancestor descendant')`

> Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

```
var str = $('#pri_txt p').text();
```

---

If you're looking for the first paragraph, use the `:first` selector

```
var str = $('#pri_txt p:first').text();
```

---

If you're searching for a specific paragraph, use the `:eq(index)` selector. Where index is the 0-based index of the element you're looking for in relation to the parent:

```
var str = $('#pri_txt p:eq(10)').text();
```

Comment: The DIV may have more than one paragraph. Will that make any difference? I just want the text from the first. Sorry it was not fully explained in the question.